# What is equivalent of leiningen :repl-options {:init-ns 'user} for tools.deps in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm using Cursive and I set aliases to `dev`, when I run the REPL it does not load the namespace that defined in deps configuration file:

```clj
 :aliases {:dev {:main-opts ["--init" "src/my/server/core.clj"
                             "--eval" "(my.server.core/-main)"]}}
```

Comment: You can do it like this:
https://github.com/seancorfield/dot-clojure/blob/master/deps.edn#L160
You can use `-e` to execute arbitrary code, or if you have a -main function, like you do, you can use:
`"-m" "my.server.core"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this at the command-line and it worked as expected, loading `my.server.core` and then running its `-main` function, so I suspect that Cursive is using `-R` on aliases rather than `-A` so it is only pulling in `:extra-deps` and not `:main-opts` (that's just a guess, I don't use Cursive). My best suggestion is to ask in the `#cursive` channel on the Clojurians Slack as that is the primary channel for Cursive support (as far as I know).

I'll also highlight Krisztian's comment that you could use `"-m" "my.server.core"` as your entire `:main-opts` since `-m` will load the namespace and run the `-main` within it.

However, those options are *not* the same as Leiningen's `:init-ns` -- what I think you need is:

```clj
{:aliases {:dev {:main-opts ["-e" "(require,'my.server.core)"
                             "-e" "(in-ns,'my.server.core)"]}}}
```

When you specify `:main-opts`, that will suppress starting a REPL:

```sh
$ clj -A:dev
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x3dddbe65 "my.server.core"]
$
```

So you need to add `-r` to tell the Clojure CLI that you also want a REPL started:

```sh
clj -A:dev -r
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x433ffad1 "my.server.core"]
my.server.core=> (doc -main)
-------------------------
my.server.core/-main
([& args])
  I don't do a whole lot ... yet.
nil
my.server.core=>
```